# How to avoid Website folder being exposed by directory browsing

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I used Custom error in webconfig and redirecting to 404new template while getting 403 status.

```
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="/404redirect.html" responseMode="Redirect" />
        <error statusCode="403" subStatusCode="14" path="/404redirect.html" responseMode="Redirect" />
    </httpErrors>
```

It's working. But while changing url to open few extension files like .txt, .js, .map., are can be viewed.

I used Handlers to restrict few extension files except ".html"(We are using to show report).it ignores .html also and shown 404 dufault page.

how to restrict this being exposed.